# How to find how many json endpoints an api has

Tags: json, api, server-side

I’m in the middle of making an Express app. It’s just a learning project.

I’m getting some info from an Anime api called jikan.me, it provides info about different Anime series like a picture url and synopsis.

For example one is at `https://api.jikan.me/anime/16` .

Now, the jikan api might have a json endpoint at `anime/1` but there's nothing at `anime/2`.

I want to find a list of all the numbers (`https://api.jikan.me/anime/[numbers]`) that actually contain endpoints.

I've tried simply going to `https://api.jikan.me/anime` but it returns `error: No ID/Path Given`.

I'm expecting there is likely no absolute answer to this problem but that I might learn something about server-side code along the way.

Where would I begin to look to find this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit late but, Jikan is an unofficial REST API for MyAnimeList. The IDs are respective to the IDs on MAL. For example; https://myanimelist.net/anime/1 can be parsed through https://api.jikan.moe/anime/1 but the ID 2 does not exist on MAL. It's a 404, hence that error.

To initially get some IDs, you can try the [search endpoint](https://jikan.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/search).

Furthermore, I'll be releasing REST 2.2 quite soon (this month) which will give you the ability to parse from pages like [these](https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php) and thus you'll get another endpoint that provides a handful of IDs to get their data from.

Source: I'm the developer of Jikan

Comment: Thanks Irfan, I've begun to develop the code to cycle through the REST API and collect all the IDs with endpoints in them. By the end of it I should have a database containing all the Anime titles with their respective IDs. https://github.com/seanwarman/browseAnime

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in the documentation it's probably information not available to you... a REST api needs to be specifically configured to offer certain endpoints, that number at the end might just be an ID that's searched for in an internal database and there's no way for the application to know if there's gonna be something there; all they can do is return an error message for you to handle as is the case here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I thought this might be the case.

Comment: If you're just picking random entries for your learning project, what I usually do is catch this error message and retry with another random number. Some APIs also offer an endpoint that will return a random object, if that helps. If not then you can always filter them out if you're presenting a list, or prepare a more complete error message for the user if they're specifically requesting data that doesn't exist.

Comment: By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow! Remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem/answered your question!